# Home Page not loading properly in magento

Tags: magento2.3, installation

While I am try to load magento home after installation, page not loading properly.
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you checking into window?

Comment: @Sakthivel were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

open cmd or terminal in root directory and run static content command

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

then clean your cache

```
php bin/magento c:c
```

hope that helps

Comment: I used to run this command in comment terminal,
cd xampp/htdocs/e-commerce
C : \xampp/htdocs/e-commerce >php bin/magento s:s:d -f

It generate error "php is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: ok run it there

Answer (score 0):

#### After installing Magento,

**Deploy the theme** by default on **first time LUMA theme will be enabled**

Try below commands to get it done

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` // this help to upgrade or the module which newly added or updated in some point.
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` // **for default or production mode**, this will help to deploy the all themes which all are able in magento,

**Assuming you executing all these commands just after magento install**, because `default magento mode is default`, if you changed to developer mode by running( `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`) then in above command need to added (-f)

so for developer mode run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` **// for developer mode**

3. `php bin/magento cache:clean`

then **go to store-front** hope you will get your expected output.

---

**Note** : some time installing XAMPP or  PHP first time, it not set environment variable for PHP

so running php command that time we are getting error : **"php is not recognized as an internal or external command"**

to solved this we need to **set  environment variable**. I am assuming XAMPP is install in C: drive  so **php path is `C:\xampp\php`**  in your case might be something else but just to go to php folder in xampp and copy the path
and added into your **PATH environment variable** or follow these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619960/2904155).

**Then close your command prompt and restart again** (Important if you do not restart your command prompt then changes will not be reflected so best to restart XAMPP and command prompt).